# Include JSP on menu item click

Tags: html, jsp

I have a main JSP page with the header and the footer, while the content of the pages is located in another JSP pages. I want to click on the menu item and load linked page via

```
<jsp:include page="page.jsp">
```

What i do:

This is index.jsp:

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.jsp">index</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.jsp">page</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>


/*Dynamic Content*/

<footer></footer>
```

If i click on the second link i want to include page.jsp that contains only the code for the  central part of the page

Comment: and what have you tried? what is the exact problem?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.Please elaborate clearly

Comment: Hope this more clear...

Comment: Still not clear. If you want to include another page after a click of a link, you need a third page to do the including.

Comment: Use javascript and on link click load page with ajax or simple make it visible.

Comment: developerwjk the page that i want to include contains only the central part of the page. It is not an entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with request object in this way:

In the JSP page:

```
<header>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?page=home">index</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page=search">search</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<%if(request.getParameter("page").equals("home")){%>
    <jsp:include page="index.jsp">
 <%}else %>
    <jsp:include page="search.jsp">
```

That's it!