# call jsp:include attribute on button

Tags: html, jsp

Suppose I have a button

```
<input type="button" />
```

Now I have to call view through

```
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

How would it work that when I click on the button it calls index.jsp on the same page.

Comment: these questions may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304669/include-jsp-on-menu-item-click  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162450/how-to-include-a-jsp-inside-another-jsp-using-javascript

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.